# Is there any way to edit DWG file using Autodesk Viewer Extensions like Edit2D or any other custom extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to edit 2D/3D models using the Autodesk Edit2D extension.

But I am getting the below error

1. A 2D model is needed to adjust the viewport
2. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is undefined
   value https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.0/extensions/Edit2D/Edit2D.min.js:19 Edit2D.min.js:19:80355

Let me know if it is possible or any other possible solution

Comment: Please add some more details on what you've tried.

Comment: If editing the DWG is the intention I would suggest to better consider the use of Design Automation for AutoCAD, this will generate a new model with the changes to the paramenters you are looking to do. the Edit2D provides tools for displaying and editing 2D shapes in Forge Viewer.